# Jquery: Why can't I access a button in a modal?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using jQuery ajax to get the entire contents of a Bootstrap modal.  Here's the javascript:

```
$.get('/user/modal', {
    id : datum.id
}).done(function (data) {
    $(data).modal('toggle');
    $('#my-btn').click(function () {
        console.log('Button was clicked!');
    });
});
```

Here is the modal html, as retrieved by the ajax call:

```
<div class="modal fade temp-modal" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <button type="button" id="my-btn">Click Me</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the click handler for the button does not work.  Why?  Whatever I do I can't seem to get a hold of it!

Comment: you can declare $('#my-btn').click(function () {
        console.log('Button was clicked!');
    }); outside of the ajax code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the `data` is dynamically loaded, you need to delegate the event:

```
$(document).on('click', '#my-btn', function () {
```

Why this has to be done?

When DOM elements are dynamically loaded such as your case ***the requested page has done the event registration for the found elements*** and the elements which are dynamically added to the DOM such as yours via ajax or via `document.createElement()` etc. You need to delegate the event to the closest static parent or to the `document` or `document.body` which are always available.

Comment: Hi Jai, this worked, but I don't understand why.  Surely I can add an event handler to an element whenever I like, so long as the element exists on the page at that point in time?

Comment: @KimPrince You can see you are not appending the data in the DOM but you just transformed the data to modal, as that element has been registered as modal so that one doesn't exist yet in the DOM.

Comment: Ah!  That's Jai, that makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to look up for your button in incomming `data` not within the `document`.

```
$.get('/user/modal', {
    id : datum.id
}).done(function (data) {
    $(data).modal('toggle');
    $(data).find('#my-btn').click(function () {
        console.log('Button was clicked!');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was try your code and I've finished to get a result

Please see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mLhzupsf/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="modal fade temp-modal" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <button type="button" id="my-btn">Click Me</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS** with JQuery 2.2.2

```
$.get('/').done(function (data) {
    //$(data).modal('toggle');
    $('#my-btn').click(function () {
        console.log('Button was clicked!');
    });
});
```

Please notice that I haev to deactive the line where you want to toggle the modal. But the button click event triggered